# How to call popup after popup with form submission without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have one pop popup form after filling that form(validations) then it will call another popup form
This is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post" name="mobnumber" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm-otp" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-groups">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileNumber" placeholder="otp" name="mobileNumber" required="required">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-groups">
        <div class=" col-sm-12 text-center">
            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">SEND OTP</button>-->
            <input type="submit" value="SendOTP'" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

OTP Popup form

```
<!--enter otp-->
<div class="modal fade" id="enter-otp" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="ex1.php" method="post" name="otp" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="userotp" id="userotp" minlength="5" maxlength="5" required="required" placeholder="Enter OTP"
                        aria-required="true" type="text">
                </div>
                <input name="loginOTP" value="1" type="hidden">
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input class="btn btn-info" value="Verify" type="submit">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--enter otp form end-->
```

Popup calling fine but i want to validate that form form and after that will call popup, but validation is not calling only popup calling..
How to call popup after validating another form with popup and submission using jquery ajax...........I mean after clicking on id submit in first form then open other popup(id=enter-otp)

Ajax:

```
           $(document).ready(function(){
           alert("fsdg");
        $("#frm-otp").submit(function() {

       var mobnum = $(this).val('mobileNumber'); 

          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url('verify-mobilenumber'); ?>",
           data: {mobnum: mobnum},
           success: function(data) {
              alert("Form With PopUp Opened");
          }
          });
         });
           });
```

I want mobile number value in second popup.How to put popup in this function

Comment: Please check i haved formated the code

Comment: Where is your code for the popup exactly?